# Reset cookies in Scrapy without disabling them

Tags: cookies, scrapy, web-crawler

I use CrawlSpider to crawl a website. The website detects my spider using cookies. If I disable them, it also detects that I am a robot. So how to use new cookies in each request.

My spider is pretty simple :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import requests
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor



class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'example'
    allowed_domains = ['www.example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/items']
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/items/.'),deny=('sendMessage')), follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/item/[a-z\+]+\-[0-9]+') ,deny=('sendMessage')), callback='parse_item', follow=False),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        #parsing the page et yielding data
```

PS: I'm using tor to change ip every x seconds.

Comment: new cookies for each request is the same as not using cookies.

Comment: @eLRuLL Are you sure? How can we verify this? knowing that when COOKIES_ENABLED is False, COOKIES_DEBUG does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved !

I use the folowing code :

```
def newsession(self, request):
    session_id = random.randint(0,900000)
    tagged = request
    tagged.meta.update(cookiejar=session_id)
    return tagged
```

In **Rule** I call newsession function through **process_request** (thanks Tomáš) :

```
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/item/[a-z\+]+\-[0-9]+') ,deny=('sendMessage')), process_request='newsession', callback='parse_item', follow=False),
```

Comment: this should be the same as using `COOKIES_ENABLED=False`, as you aren't combining cookies between requests, which means that you are not "sending" stored cookies to the next request, only receiving them. `COOKIES_ENABLED=False` should even work better than this approach, because you are using a random number which could still create duplicated cookiejars, which means sending the stored cookies back to the server.

Answer (score 2):

You can set cookies for each [`Request`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects) via `cookies` parameter. It's a bit more complicated when using `CrawlSpider` class, because it generates requests for you based on rules. However, you can add `process_request` parameter to your [`Rule`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Rule). From the documentation:

> `process_request` is a callable, or a string (in which case a method from the spider object with that name will be used) which will be called with every request extracted by this rule, and must return a request or None (to filter out the request).

Hence, implement that method and add `cookies` parameter to each request passed in and then return the modified request.

Comment: I do not know the values ​​of the cookies to put. It is the server that generates it (id of the session for example). How can I tell Scrapy to ask the server for new cookies?

Comment: Then you probably have to extract them from each response's headers.